# Byte Array to Vector String

Tags: java, android, vector, arrays

I am writing a client server application where the server sends a `Vector String` object over `OutputStream` and on the client side I am receiving it as `Byte Array`. Now how do I get the `Vector String` object back from this `Byte array` ?

Comment: Just a question: why don't you use ObjectOutputStream and/or Serializable objects instead?

Comment: What is a Vector String? How is it serialized by the sender? Java serialization? XML? JSON? custom mechanism? Show us some code.

Comment: actually the server can send simple string as well as Vector of Strings...now on the client side I am receiving everything in byte array in a TCP thread...now depending on the current Android Activity on display I need to convert the received bytes to simple string or vector of strings...so i dont think i can use ObjectOutputStream...may be

Answer (score 0):

Don't send object over stream. Serialize Vector<String> object on server side and deserialize it on device.
You can serialize object using e.g. JSON. There's a great free libarary from Google that does most of work for you, it's called GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: Since both server and client seems to be running on Java, he can skip the JSon step and simply serialize / deserialize the object (Vector is Serializable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send on correct way, using serializable or write the length first

Comment: but how do I differentiate on the receivers end if the bytes I received is a simple string or are a Vector of strings...and if they are Vector of Strings the how do I get them from the received bytes...I can get strings like String foo = new String(bytes)...but not Vectors